# Indexing dynamic objects in elasticsearch nest

Tags: class, object, elasticsearch, dynamic, nest

Elastic search generally works with pre-defined classes . How do I work with dynamic classes. 
eg: Suppose I want to search a particular field then

```
var result = clientConnection.Search<**TicketData**>(

s => s
.Aggregations(

a => a
    .DateRange(

"L1", d => d
        .Field(p => p.timestamp)
            .Ranges(
            r => r.To("2016-10-09T15:01:06+00:00"),
            r => r.From("2016-09-27T02:09:17+00:00")
        )
    )
)
);
```

Here the ticketdata class has to be defined beforehand. Can we have something like

```
var result = clientConnection.Search<ANYDYNAMICCLASS>(s => s

.Aggregations(a => a

.DateRange("L1", d => d

.Field(p => p.timestamp)

           .Ranges(
            r => r.To("2016-10-09T15:01:06+00:00"),
            r => r.From("2016-09-27T02:09:17+00:00")
        )
    )
)
);
```

Can a dynamic class/ dynamic object work with this ? please give an example how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch works with JSON documents, it's not tied to C# POCOs. With a strongly typed language like C# however, it makes a lot of sense to model documents in Elasticsearch as POCOs in your application but you don't have to.

For example, we could use `dynamic` as the document type to search, and use the `.Index()` and `.Type()` methods to specify the indices and types, respectively

```
var result = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .Index("index-name")
    .Type("type-name")
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .DateRange("L1", d => d
            .Field("timestamp")
            .Ranges(
                r => r.To("2016-10-09T15:01:06+00:00"),
                r => r.From("2016-09-27T02:09:17+00:00")
            )
        )
    )
```

);

You can also work with Elasticsearch.Net directly through the `.LowLevel` property on the client and work with streams, bytes or strings as well.